# Wrap zip files in a folder

Tags: bash, zip

When zipping a bunch of files, is there a way to wrap them in a folder in the process?

```
zip -r archive.zip \
    file1.txt \
    file2.txt \
    things/*/*.txt
```

I'd like the zip to contain a **folder** that contains the `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `things` folder.

Is there a way to do it with zip without having to copy all these files to a folder and then zipping the folder instead?

Comment: Why is "copy all these files to a folder and then zipping the folder" a problem?

Comment: There's... a lot. And I do it often. If there was a way to skip it, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Have a trick for you to make this work using a *soft link*.

1. cd to a directory that does **not** hold your files
2. create a soft link to the folder that holds your files `ln -s /folderWithMyStuff containingFolder`
3. zip the soft link `zip -r archive.zip containingFolder`

Your files will now be saved in archive.zip under a folder called containingFolder

Comment: This didn't work for me since I don't have a folder that holds my files, I have a folder that holds a bunch of files and then I cherry pick the files and folders from it to the zip file. Ended up unzipping the zip to a folder and then zipping that folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up unzipping the zip to a folder and then zipping that folder.

```
zip -r archive.zip \
    file1.txt \
    file2.txt \
    things/*/*.txt

unzip archive.zip -d archive

rm archive.zip

zip -r archive.zip archive

rm -rf ./archive
```